# What is the `isolate primitive` mentioned in the documentation of the "cereal" package?

Tags: haskell, definition, primitive

There is an extensive collection of unique words in on the Haskell repository, cabal, (very slight exaggeration). Anyway today's term is [*isolate primitive*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal). What is an isolate primitive? How does it compare to a non-isolate primitive? Unfortunately, I don't have the background to know most of the Haskell parlance, and Google isn't helping much on this one.

The nomenclature that I'm familiar with defines *primitive* as a type that has no super-type, and I've never seen *isolate* as a prefix anywhere.

Comment: The term only seems to appear once on the Web in a Haskell context, so it could just be a typo for something.

Comment: The question in answerable, he shows initiative, etc. Why is it -1? +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'cereal' package provides a primitive function,

```
isolate :: Int -> Get a -> Get a
```

which is unique to that package. This function "isolates" a parsing action to operate using a fixed block of bytes. If the parsing function consumes less or more bytes, that is an error.

Thus, as opposed to binary, cereal "introduces an isolate primitive for parser isolation"

- The documentation for '[isolate](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cereal/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Data-Serialize-Get.html#v%3Aisolate)'
- It's [implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cereal/0.3.0.0/doc/html/src/Data-Serialize-Get.html#isolate)

Answer (score 3):

Isn't 'isolate' the name of a primitive defined in HackageDB::cereal ?

Comment: Oho, so the typo is missing backticks around isolate.

Comment: This might just be it, I assumed it was a esoteric term that I just didn't know.

Comment: where does it define in the source isolate?

Answer (score 3):

The `isolate` parser is called "primitive" because it is a simple parser that:

- Can't be built from the other, provided parsers (not if it's really
  primitive).
- Can be used in combination with other parsers to build more complex
  parsers.

It's a "primitive parser" in the same way that `uint` is a primitive type.